# ImageMagick creating unique filename

Tags: php, html, imagemagick

I am trying to generate images using ImageMagick, please check the code below:

```
<?
$label=$_POST["label"];
$image =$_POST["image"];
$cmd = " -background transparent label:\"$label\" -stroke red -strokewidth 0 ".
"  \( -clone 0 -tile \"" . $image . "[0]\" -stroke red -strokewidth 0 -gravity center  -annotate +0+0 \"$label\" \) ".
"  \( -clone 0 -tile \"" . $image . "[1]\" -stroke red -strokewidth 0 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 \"$label\" \) ".
"  \( -clone 0 -tile \"" . $image . "[2]\" -stroke red -strokewidth 0 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 \"$label\" \)  ".
"  \( -clone 0 -tile \"" . $image . "[3]\" -stroke red -strokewidth 0 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 \"$label\" \)  ".


 "  -delete 0 -set delay 20 -loop 0 -trim +repage -layers Optimize ";

$array=array();
echo "<pre>";
exec("convert $cmd masked.gif 2>&1", $array);
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>";
echo "</pre>";
echo "<img src='masked.gif'>";
?>
```

Above code works fine by generating an image named as `masked.gif`, but I need to do two things now:

1. Generated image should have a unique filename{every time it should generate different file name}
2. Generated image should be saved in different folder not the root directory, let's say the directory name as "coolpics" ,

Please help me to fix this. Your response is appreciated.

Comment: There are many thing you can do for a unique name like md5($some_data) or you can use microtime as well. As for saving in an other folder, did you try to give the path you want in `exec`, did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For unique filename, check the [uniqid](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function.
2. For saving directory, just concatenate it with the filename, something like:

```
// your command here

$directory = "/data/images/coolpics/"
$name = uniqid();
exec(escapeshellcmd("convert $cmd $directory$name 2>&1"), $array);
```

Note that you're passing POST values directly to a system command, this can be a very serious **security fail**. Use [escapeshellcmd](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) to make sure your system is safe.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to get an unique file name is to use a timestamp (`microtime()` ([doc reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)) for instance). To save the image in another folder just add the path to your exec parameters.

The whole exec command would look like this:

```
exec("convert $cmd /your/path/".str_replace(".","-",microtime(true)).".gif 2>&1", $array);
```